# Pandas compare next row based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame as shown in the picture:

[image: dataframe]

I want to compare the current row and the next, whether df['Time'] is the same, and df['MessageType'] is 'D' followed by 'A'. If the condition is satisfied, remove the row that contains 'D' and rename the value 'A' to 'AMEND'.

Something like...

```
if df['Time'] (current) == df['Time'] (next) & df['MessageType'] (current) == 'D' is followed by df['MessageType'] (next) == 'A':
del current row
df['MessageType'] (next_row).rename({'A': 'AMEND'})
```

Comment: you can use the shift function in pandas , with `periods = -1` [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: show your sample df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load both of the columns from the data frame into different lists and iterate over them to check if the condition is followed & combine your updated lists to generate a new data frame.

This is a very brute force way to do this but will give you enough idea to come up with a more space-efficient approach iterating directly over the data frame. Coming up with the best answer yourself might cheer you up too.

```py
import pandas as pd

Time = df['Time']
MessageType = df['MessageType']
Symbol = df['Symbol']

for i in range(len(Time)-1):
    if(Time[i] == Time[i+1] && MessageType[i] == "D" && MessageType[i+1] == "A"):
        del Time[i] # deleting the row
        del MessageType[i] # deleting the row
        del Symbol[i] # deleting the row
        MessageType[i+1] = "AMEND" # rename the message type

# creating a new dataframe with updated lists
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':Time, 'MessageType':MessageType, 'Symbol':Symbol})
```

Comment: Thank you. It does solve my problem, although the warning appears - "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy"

Comment: The SettingWithCopyWarning just ensures that the user knows they are operating on the copy of the main data frame and not the original one so changes might not reflect upon the original df. 

Try reading this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do quite a bit in one step. Think about each operation and find a way to do each sub-step. If you do you'll find that you need ways to look BOTH forward and backward in a given axis in the dataframe. Pandas has some extremely convenient functions that do this - diff() and shift(). It's also worth spending some time thinking about edge cases - Do you just want to look at the next row, or all rows below the current row?

You're trying to remove rows in the dataframe as well as change data in the dataframe. We will need to do each of these steps separately. If we remove data before we change it, we may have trouble isolating the data we need to change again.

I couldn't figure out what time format you are using in your DF, so I used datetime.datetimes. In general, I find time/datetime comparisons in Pandas difficult. If there was a way for you to change the input for this column to a float, it would simplify matters (but is not essential).

Things you're trying to do:

1. (a): Find rows with an 'A' MessageType (b): that have the same Time as the row above them and (c): the row above them has a 'D' MessageType.
2. (a): Find rows with a 'D' MessageType (b): that have the same time as the row below them and (c): the row below has an 'A' MessageType.
3. For rows found in 1, change MessageType to 'AMEND'
4. For rows found in 2, remove the row

There are many ways to go about this. I recommend using Boolean arrays and masks, especially as you're building towards an answer. The code below has a number of print statements that you can uncomment - it may help understand what's going on under the hood.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime


Symbol = ['AAD', 'AAD', 'AAD', 'AAD', 'AAD', 'AAD']
Time = [datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9,30,39,55), datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9,30,39,90),
        datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9,30,52,41), datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9,30,52,41), 
       datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9,35,0,97), datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9,35,1,33)]
MessageType = ['A', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A','A']

df=pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': Symbol, 'Time': Time, 'MessageType': MessageType})

#convert times to timedeltas
pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,'Time'])

#print(df)

FWDeqTime = df.loc[:,'Time'].diff(periods=-1) == pd.Timedelta('0 sec')
BKWeqTime = df.loc[:,'Time'].diff(periods=1) == pd.Timedelta('0 sec')

#print(FWDeqTime)
#print(FWDdf[eqTime])

msgD=df.loc[:,'MessageType'] == 'D'
msgA=df.loc[:,'MessageType'] == 'A'

#print(msgD)
#print(df[msgD])

nxtMsgA = df.loc[:,'MessageType'].shift(periods=-1) == 'A'
prevMsgD = df.loc[:,'MessageType'].shift(periods=1) == 'D'
#print(nxtMsg)
#print(df[nxtMsg])

mask1 = (msgA & BKWeqTime & prevMsgD)
#print(mask1)
#print(df[mask1])

df.loc[mask1,'MessageType'] = 'AMEND'
#print(df)

mask2 = (msgD & FWDeqTime & nxtMsgA)
#print(mask2)

df=df[~ mask2]
print(df)
```